# retrieving data from coredata where entity has NSSet

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nsset

I am trying to use a predicate to get data where the data i want to search on is in a `NSSet`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *categories;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *otherDetails;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *id;
```

the `NSSet` categories is made up from another entity and contains:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *id;
```

then try getting this via a predicate

```
NSFetchRequest *fetcher =[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
fetcher.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@categories in  %@", catList];
```

where catList is:

```
NSmutableArray *catList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and is populated with data

this is then giving me the following error

```
'NSInvalidArgumetException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate: (categories IN {"this", "that"});
```

I tried changing it to use the `NSSet` fields like such

```
fetcher.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@categories.name in  %@", catList];
```

but this didn't work.

if i change the predicate to use the `NSString` it does not error but as the data is different no results are returned.

```
fetcher.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@categories in  %@", catList];
```

So what must I do to use the predicate to do the query on the `NSSet`?

Update:
I have since found this [How to check if an objects is inside of a NSSet of objects by using predicateWithFormat in CoreData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446673/how-to-check-if-an-objects-is-inside-of-a-nsset-of-objects-by-using-predicatewit) that would possibly solve the question posted, but i have simpliefied this a little too much.

what i actually have is another entity with a whole heap of details I am search on that then has a many to one relationship with my "MyEntity" entity.

MySearchEntity:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *searchField1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *searchField2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyEntity *myEntity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *id;
```

and a fetchrequest like this

```
NSFetchRequest *fetcher =[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MySearchEntity"];
fetcher.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myEntity.otherDetails CONTAINS %@ && searchField1 <= %f && searchField2 >= %f && myEntity.categories.name in  %@", catList];
```

so the rest of the statement works but i am still unable to get filter it by the MyEntities many to many relationship with categories.

Comment: What is the goal of your predicate?

Comment: It is to limit the categories to those selected added to catList.

Comment: Since for each object, categories is a set of (many) objects, what exactly do you want to fetch? All objects whose categories is equal to catList or a subset of catList? Or all objects that have at least one category of catList?

Comment: catList is a subset of all possible categories (set via user interacion elsewhere).

Comment: That does not answer my question. Which objects do you want to fetch?

Comment: Sorry,  I want to get all the objects who have at least on category of catList.  I have also update the question to fully explain the level of query as I reaslised i had oversimplified it.

Comment: and the object i want is the MySearchEntity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the `MySearchEntity` objects where the related `MyEntity` object has at least one category in the given set, you would use the predicate

```
NSArray *catList = array of Category objects;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY myEntity.categories IN %@", catList];
```

or, if the categories are given by name:

```
NSArray *catList = array of NSString objects;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY myEntity.categories.name IN %@", catList];
```

Comment: Fantastic.  The "ANY" was what i was missing and it makes the world of difference.  Thanks Martin for you assistance with this.  I have marked this as the answer.